# Trabalhando com arrays e condições

Tags: php, array

Pessoal possuo três arrays recebidos via POST:

```
[campo_habilita]    => Array ( [0] => Habilitado 
                               [1] => Habilitado 
                               [2] => Habilitado ) 

[campo_nome]        => Array ( [0] => Nome 1 
                               [1] => Nome 2 
                               [2] => Nome 3 )

[campo_nascimento] => Array (  [0] => 15-05-1990 
                               [1] => 27-02-1983 
                               [2] => 14-03-1987 )
```

Preciso montar algumas condições (if) antes de fazer a inserção dos dados no banco, porém, não sei como montar o foreach integrando os três arrays, para assim testar os dados submetidos. (não sei se este é o comando a ser usado para isso)

Uma das condições é:

- se o (campo_habilita='Habilitado' e campo_nome='') = "mostrar erro";

Uma outra condição é:

- se o (campo_habilita='Habilitado' e (funcaoTestaData(campo_nascimento)==false) = "mostrar erro";

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Nessa situação um for normal parece melhor, ai vc indexa os 3 arrays pelo mesmo indice (`$i`) e faz as comparações.

Comment: como que eu monto esse for, rray?

Answer (score 3):

Como o [@rray disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155263/trabalhando-com-arrays-e-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es#comment320338_155263) você pode fazê-lo, traves de indexação:

```
$_POST['campo_habilita'] = Array (
    0 => 'Habilitado',
    1 => 'Habilitado',
    2 => 'Habilitado',
);

$_POST['campo_nome'] = Array (
    0 => 'Nome 1', 
    1 => 'Nome 2', 
    2 => 'Nome 3'
);

$_POST['campo_nascimento'] = Array (
    0 => '15-05-1990',
    1 => '27-02-1983',
    2 => '14-03-1987',
);
```

#### Foreach

```
foreach ($_POST['campo_habilita'] as $k => $value){
    $habilitado = $value;
    $nome       = $_POST['campo_nome'][$k];
    $nascimento = $_POST['campo_nascimento'][$k];

    // aqui você testa os valores;
}
```

#### For

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['campo_habilita']); $i++){
    $habilitado = $_POST['campo_habilita'][$i];
    $nome       = $_POST['campo_nome'][$i];
    $nascimento = $_POST['campo_nascimento'][$i];

    // aqui você testa os valores;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigos!